# Java_opts settings for a program

Tags: java, maven, java-opts

I need to set Java_opts memory things for only one Java app. My program is a Maven project. Is there any way that I can just set it to my program, not the whole environment?

Comment: Using the maven-exec-plugin? Surefire? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you're executing your program during the maven life build, you can set the MAVEN_OPTS.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? how can I set there?

Comment: Which might not help if maven-exec-plugin is used (but depends on the configuration).